# Planetscale, Prisma relationmode complex error

Tags: mysql, prisma, next-auth, next.js13, planetscale

I'm using Next Auth, so I want to create a Clan model, that also contains Users.

But I'm getting mapping error.
I've always used foreignKeys, so I think I don't understand how this relationModel = prisma works.

Could you give me an example or tell me what may I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!